# Как лучше сверстать блок «Наши партнеры»

Tags: css, вёрстка, разметка

Подскажите, можно ли сверстать такой блок на гридах и как лучше оформить разметку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется обойтись структурой:

```
<section class='partners'>
    <div class='partners__list'><!-- тут список img !--></div>
    <div class='partners__info'><!-- блок «нам доверяют» !--></div>  
</section>
```

Если нельзя буду рад советам. Не хочется логотипы разбивать на 2 обертки по понятными причинам. Сам блок будет статичен, но хочется максимально чистенько.

Comment: Увы, "максимально чистенько" - это разбить на две обёртки)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать на float реализовать. Вот пример

```css
.partners__info {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid yellow;

    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.partners__list {
    display: inline;
}

img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.active {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class='partners'>
    <div class='partners__list'>
        <div class='partners__info'>
            <div>
                <h3>20 лет нам доверяют</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='partners__list'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg' class='active'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>
            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>

            <img src='https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/282/400/912/hamburger-history-of-mcdonald-s-nyse-mcd-food-mcdonald-s-logo-png.jpg'>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ну точно)))) 2 года уже не юзаю флоаты кроме как по прямому назначению))) а тут еще и clearfix можно из старых проектов подтянуть!!! От души))